# Sum of ingredients in recipes model to create shoppinglist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, many-to-many

I Have a shoppinglist model which has many recipes, which again has many ingredients.

```
class Shoppinglist < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :shoppinglistrecipezations
   has_many :recipes, :through => :shoppinglistrecipezations
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :shoppinglistrecipezations
 has_many :shoppinglists, :through => :shoppinglistrecipezations
 has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredienzations
 has_many :ingredienzations
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredienzations
 has_many :ingredienzations
end
```

When I add several recipes to the shopping model (some of them have the same ingredients) I want to print a list of all the ingrediens in the shoppinglist and the right amount of ingredients. Shoppinglistingredienzations has an integer "Persons" to tell how many persons served should be calculated for and Recipe has a persons variable to show how many persons the recipe is for. Ingredienzations contains the amount, measurement type (grams, teaspoons etc.) and recipe_id.

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: how do I sum the different ingredientz for each shoppinglist so I can loop through them as in for each xx in shoppinglist.ingredientz

Comment: Well, I still don't get the idea but let's skip this for now. The model schema does not seem to be logic for me. `Shoppinglist` should have many `Ingredient`, not `Recipe`. When you're going to shop, you're not buying recipes, but ingredients for these recipes.

Comment: the "problem" is I have recipes that I add to the shoppinglist and would like to just sum them up with a function, but maybe I should just add the ingredients directly after adding the recipe to the shoppinglist... that would solve the problem although not as elegantly maybe.

Comment: Well, since you have access to ingredients through recipes, it's no problem here. However, you also need access to ingredienzations to get the amount and measurement type. What do you mean by 'sum the up'? The idea is to get all ingredients for given shoppinglist with calculated amount of each ingredient for given measurement type?

Comment: I would say, the Albin answer is correct. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Shoppinglist.where(id: list_id).joins({recipes: : ingredients}).group('ingredients.name').sum('ingredients.amount')
```

assuming your `Ingredient` model has the attributes amount and name. It becomes much more tricky if you have units on you amounts. But this query can be rewritten to make that work as well.