# ActiveRecord: complex query with Sum, Join, Group By and Select multiple fields

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've waisted few days for this query but still not figured out the solution.

**There are my models**

```
class UserObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "user_objects"
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :the_object, class_name: 'Object'
end

class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'objects'

  has_many :user_objects, class_name: 'UserObject', foreign_key: :the_object_id, inverse_of: :the_object
  has_many :users, through: :user_objects
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "users"
end
```

**Here is my schema**

```
  create_table "objects", force: true do |t|
    t.float    "importance",        default: 0.5, null: false
  end

  create_table "user_objects", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "the_object_id"
    t.float    "score",              default: 0.0,   null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
  end
```

I need a query for select `objects.importance` and sum of `user_objects.score`. But also I have to select for query only those `objects` which belongs to `user1` and `user2`.

I wrote a query for select objects.importance

```
Object.select("objects.importance").joins(:user_objects).
                                    where(user_objects: {user_id: [user1_id,user2_id]}).
                                    group(objects: :id).
                                    having('COUNT("user_objects"."id")=2')
```

And it's converted to

```
SELECT objects.importance FROM "objects" INNER JOIN "user_objects" ON "user_objects"."the_object_id" = "objects"."id" WHERE "user_objects"."user_id" IN (2, 7) GROUP BY "objects"."id" HAVING COUNT("user_objects"."id")=2
```

When I executed this query I got this response

```
[#<Object id: nil, importance: 0.5>, #<Object id: nil, importance: 0.5>]
```

Quantity of objects in response is OK. But I still don't know how to count in this query sum of `user_objects.score`. Next query doesn't work

```
Object.select("objects.importance, SUM(user_objects.score)").
       joins(:user_objects).
       where(user_objects: {user_id: [user1_id,user2_id]}).
       group(objects: :id).having('COUNT("user_objects"."id")=2')
```

I expected in response something like this

```
[#[<Object id: nil, importance: 0.5>, 0.2], #[<Object id: nil, importance: 0.5>,0.3]]
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Comment: since the logic is simple, why not raw SQL?

Comment: Because raw SQL is less readable and it's not Rails-way

Comment: SQL is the lingua franca in relational database land. The many framework dialects are **pale imitations** implementing crippled subsets of the functionality and not even close in readability. Of course, if your mother tongue is Finnish, you would find Finnish to be "more readable" than English. But everything has to be translated to SQL either way, because that's the language of the RDBMS after all. SQL could have been devised more cleverly, but the same is true for weird aspects of the English language and it's the lingua franca of the world and we are using it here.

Comment: Is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829121/sum-of-ingredients-in-recipes-model-to-create-shoppinglist/26838879#26838879

Comment: Erwin, you are right that SQL is a lingua franca, but in Rails code using of ActiveRecord is more preferable. And there "English" raw SQL is less readable cause it surrounded with "Finnish" Ruby code.

Comment: Albin, it is similar but I need select not just a sum but also a one field.

Comment: @TetyanaChupryna: Fair enough. For special needs it may still be a good idea to allow some raw SQL. May not be necessary for this one, I am sure there is a solution around the corner. Unfortunately, neither the "Finnish" nor the plain English explanation led me to understand the problem. A demo with sample values and the desired result might clarify things.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I assumed that my question isn't clear for so I updated my question, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Not to me. This doesn't make any sense: `But I still don't know how to count in this query sum of user_objects.score`. And this is ambiguous in multiple ways: `But also I have to select for query only those objects which belongs to user1 and user2.` I am sure the task is simple, once you can describe it unambiguously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок. I've found a solution. Here is right query.

```
Object.joins(:user_objects).
       where(user_objects: {user_id: [user1_id,user2_id]}).
       group(objects: :id).
       having('COUNT("user_objects"."id")=2').
       pluck("objects.importance, SUM(user_objects.score)")
```

Problem was in `select` method because it creates *an object* of a class which invoke this method. So it is impossible to choose in one `select` attributes of few models. But `pluck` return resulting array with *values* of fields So we can choose fields from different tables. 
That`s it. So simple!